# why does winscp send an SSH_FXP_MKDIR and an SSH_FXP_SETSTAT packet when it seems like a single SSH_FXP_MKDIR would suffice?

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

In section [6.6 Creating and Deleting Directories](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-6.6) in the SFTP specs it says the following:

```
    New directories can be created using the SSH_FXP_MKDIR request.  It
   has the following format:

        uint32     id
        string     path
        ATTRS      attrs
```

Per that the permissions of a newly created directory should be settable through the SSH_FXP_MKDIR packet. Given that why is it that WinSCP doing this?:

```
. 2020-03-28 15:25:35.569 Real path is '/home/vagrant/New folder 3'
. 2020-03-28 15:25:35.569 Canonified: "/home/vagrant/New folder 3"
> 2020-03-28 15:25:35.569 Type: SSH_FXP_MKDIR, Size: 39, Number: 1550
> 2020-03-28 15:25:35.569 0E,00,00,06,0E,00,00,00,1A,2F,68,6F,6D,65,2F,76,61,67,72,61,6E,74,2F,4E,65,
> 2020-03-28 15:25:35.569 77,20,66,6F,6C,64,65,72,20,33,00,00,00,00,

> 2020-03-28 15:25:35.571 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 43, Number: 2313
> 2020-03-28 15:25:35.571 09,00,00,09,09,00,00,00,1A,2F,68,6F,6D,65,2F,76,61,67,72,61,6E,74,2F,4E,65,
> 2020-03-28 15:25:35.571 77,20,66,6F,6C,64,65,72,20,33,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,07,
```

ie. the attrs field of the SSH_FXP_MKDIR request is blank and it's a subsequent SSH_FXP_SETSTAT that's actually setting the permissions.

Couldn't a single request be utilized instead of two?

Comment: How can you get this dump?

Comment: @Gábor - see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging